# SOLR subquery result filter

Tags: solr

I have the subquery, returning the required documents within
`variants` field

fl=`*, variants:[subquery]`

variants.q = `{!terms f=baseProduct_string v=$row.baseProduct_string}`

So, the requirement is to not return any document, for which `variants` field is  empty

I was trying to add filter queries with : `variants:[* TO *]` and also tried to use exist function for this purposes, but I keep getting

```
 "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field: \"variants\"",
    "code":400}}
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Do you need a subquery for this? What's the query you're actually running? Do you have a field that's named `variants`? (or is it queried as `"variants"` (hard to say with the error message given). `fq=variants:[* TO *]` should be enough to only include documents that have variants set, but it requires you to have a field named variants already defined.

Comment: No, I don't have field `variants` on my document. It is created by subquery,and contains list of documents. Query is `*:*`

Comment: Then you can't use it in a filter query as far as I know. subqueries run per document _already in the result set_. It doesn't change the result set. However, depending on your document structure, you might be able to filter the list of documents before moving onto the subquery step. You'll have to add more context to your question (and if possible, example documents for easy experimenting) for that.